# SQL Query format to get the product_tags and not every tag in wordpress database (for jQuery autocomplete)

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

Like the title says.
I want to make an jQuery autocomplete search field in my shop that shows the tags stored in wordpress database under wp_terms. so long so good.

**my actual sql query looks like this:**

```
if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $term = $_GET['term'];
    $db_erg = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name
    FROM  wp_terms
    WHERE name LIKE '$term%'");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($db_erg, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $ERGEBNIS[] = array(
            'label' => $row['name']
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($ERGEBNIS);
    $con->close();
}
```

It now suggests me every tag in the database(table) that is like my input but I only want to show the tags that are really product_tag(wp_term_taxonomy).

So my question is: **How does the sql query need to look like when I want to accomplish my goal?**

here's a picture of the database structure:

[image: database structure]

I tried JOIN and INNERJOIN but my results are just errors or nothing... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Hey,

First of all - you should start using the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org)

Now, if we will follow the function [**get_terms**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

according to the codex the function works like this:

```
<?php get_terms( $taxonomies, $args ) ?>
```

The taxonomies are taken from `wp_term_taxonomy` 
Now the interesting part for this case is the `$args` AKA `arguments`:
Here - we should use `name__like`.

this is an example for a usage:

```
<?php $myTerms = get_terms( 'product_tag', array('name__like' => $name) ); ?>
```

This code would take terms from the `product_tag` taxonomy and use `like`, just as in an sql query. but this function know how to separate results to the taxonomy `product_tag` only, which if i understand correctly - that's what you tried to accomplish :)

if you want to get results from more than one taxonomy you should place them as and array there.
for example:

```
<?php $myTerms = get_terms( array('product_tag','something_else') , array('name__like' => $name) ); ?>
```

#### Good luck ! :)